Purview not showing Snowflake Tables Lineage
When I create a table using a SELECT statement to copy data from another table in Snowflake, the system doesn't automatically capture this dependency in the OBJECT_DEPENDENCIES view. Hence, would like to confirm is this happening due to Snowflake doesn't maintain dependencies between tables based on data copying operations like SELECT INTO or CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS)? or is the dependency stored at somewhere, which that files I can then be used to create table lineage in the Purview?
Is it because the data in the new table may be derived from another table, but Snowflake will treat the new table as an independent object without explicit dependencies on the source table's data?

The object-dependencies view does not capture dependencies necessary for Snowflake implementations. For example, the view does not record the dependency necessary to create a new table from a clone of another table.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-dependencies#limitations

Also, the list of supported dependencies is given here:https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-dependencies#label-object-dependencies-supported-objects
